# What dance is the battle between Lucciola and Cicada based on?

Tags: last-exile

In Last Exile, episode 23 ("Castling Lucciola"), the battle between Lucciola and Cicada resembles a dance routine. The actual fight begins at about 19:35 into the episode.

What type of dance is this supposed to resemble? I did a little research on it myself, and it seems to most resemble ballet. But if that's the case, then what kind of ballet?